# Send custom data when Salesforce is a SAML SSO identity provider

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, saml, identity, identity-provider

We configured Salesforce as an Identity Provider for an External App.

We want to be able to make Idp-Initiated SSO and send custom attributes with the SAML Message, for example the **Case or Account ID** the user is working on.

However,

- In the SAML connected app we are only able to send user/system data.
- Tried also to add parameters to Idp Start URL https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/idp/login?app=0sp1j0000008xxx&**attribute1=value1&attribute2=value2**... it doesn't relay custom parameters to resource provider.

Did you face a similar requirement ? 
What is your recommended approach to send Salesforce data in a SAML Assertion ?

Thanks a lot